# Create a column in Pandas that counts the number of unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried several methods to get this working and nothing works. So, I'll give my entire process here.

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to count 1 column of. The data is stored in a csv file. Here's my current method of importing it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
index  id  name  dob       visit
0      111 Joe   1/1/2000  1/1/2018
1      111 Joe   1/1/2000  1/5/2018
2      122 Bob   1/1/1999  2/8/2018
3      133 Jill  1/2/1988  7/9/2017
4      111 Joe   1/1/2000  12/31/2018
```

Because each client will have multiple lines in the dataframe based on how many visits they had, I want to create a column that includes the count of how many times their id number show up under the id column.

I've tried the following:

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby('id').id.count()
```

but this gives me NaN values for every row. If I switch to size(), again NaN. So I decided to make a series out of the results:

```
visits = df.groupby('id').id.count()
```

That gives me:

```
index  id
111    3
122    1
133    1
```

It isn't exactly what I need, but close. I then try to update my dataframe with the series:

```
visitcounts = visits.to_frame()
```

I need to get the index to be a column, and that column to have a different name.

visitcounts.rename(columns = {'id': 'visitnum'}, inplace = True)
   visitscounts['id'] = visitcounts.index

Then, to add the field back to the dataframe:

```
pd.merge(df, visitcounts, on=['id'], how='left')
```

And nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for this:

```
df['count'] = df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
```

Result:

```
   index   id  name       dob       visit  count
0      0  111   Joe  1/1/2000    1/1/2018      3
1      1  111   Joe  1/1/2000    1/5/2018      3
2      2  122   Bob  1/1/1999    2/8/2018      1
3      3  133  Jill  1/2/1988    7/9/2017      1
4      4  111   Joe  1/1/2000  12/31/2018      3
```

Comment: This worked! And skipped so many of the extraneous steps I was taking. Thanks!

Comment: Can I use this function to count on, two fields? Say, Id and visit date?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean? By two fields, you mean count of unique combinations of (id, visit)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply jpp. That's exactly what I mean, a count of unique combinations.

Comment: @EduardoX, can you please ask as a separate question - this way other users can benefit from your question + answer.

Answer (score 2):

jpp's solution is probably the cleaner way to go, but in order to clarify why your code doesn't work:

Your issue is that your `id` that you want to merge on in `visitcounts` is actually your index, and not the column named `id`:

```
>>> visitcounts
     id
id     
111   3
122   1
133   1
```

So, if you wanted to use `merge`, you could merge on the index for `visitcounts` and on the column `id`of your `df`, it should work:

```
# First rename column in visitcounts to `count`:

visitcounts.columns=['count']

# Then merge:
merged_df = pd.merge(df, visitcounts, left_on='id', right_index=True)

>>> merged_df
   index   id  name       dob       visit  count
0      0  111   Joe  1/1/2000    1/1/2018      3
1      1  111   Joe  1/1/2000    1/5/2018      3
4      4  111   Joe  1/1/2000  12/31/2018      3
2      2  122   Bob  1/1/1999    2/8/2018      1
3      3  133  Jill  1/2/1988    7/9/2017      1
```

Comment: Fantastic! That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped!